# sapui5 Internet Explorer 11 Planning Calendar is not working

Tags: sapui5

I have done an application in Web-IDE in SAPUI5 using [Planning Calendar](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendar/preview), Im able to run and execute the application perfectly in Google Chrome, But if i run the same application in IE11, Im getting below error..

**: found in negative cache: '/MyTeamCalendar.controller.js' from ./controller/MyTeamCalendar.controller.js: Syntax error**

[image]

Im not able to find the exact issue.Can someone help me how can i run the Planning Calendar in IE 11?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like `MyTeamCalender.controller.js` has a syntax error in it. The issue is most likely in newer JS syntax like array or object functions

Comment: you are right.. Actually i have used ES6 code in js. I came to know that ES6 will not support in IE... Now i converted ES6 code to Javascript. Now im able to load the page in IE. Thank you for your prompt response..